# parcel issue with loading environment variable files

Tags: parceljs

I want to delineate the environment variables in development & production environments. So I created two environment variable files ".env.development" and ".env.production", and updated the dev and build scripts to set the NODE_ENV to development and production.

But when I run the scripts (dev or build) the corresponding environment file does not load (Eg. .env.development in development environment) as mentioned in the official documentation. https://parceljs.org/env.html